# Google Charts xAxis must contain datetime

Tags: java, datetime, charts, google-visualization

I need to create a chart using Google Chart with xAxis that represents the datetime and the yAxis that represents the temperature from my sensor.

I am combining it with Java

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');

        <%
          for ( MyDateTimeFormat key : hm.keySet() ) {
              out.print("data.addRow([new Date("+key.year+","+key.month+","+key.day+","+key.hour+","+key.minute+","+key.second+"), "+hm.get(key)+"]);"); 
          }%>

        var options = {
          title: '<% out.print(((ConfigItemTemperatureSensor)item).getId()+" P"+((ConfigItemTemperatureSensor)item).getPort()+((ConfigItemTemperatureSensor)item).getPin()+" "+((ConfigItemTemperatureSensor)item).getName()); %>'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

The values of MyDateTimeFormat looks like this:

```
MyDateTimeFormat [year=2014, month=01, day=07, hour=17, minute=05, second=56]
MyDateTimeFormat [year=2014, month=01, day=07, hour=17, minute=06, second=01]
MyDateTimeFormat [year=2014, month=01, day=07, hour=17, minute=06, second=06]
MyDateTimeFormat [year=2014, month=01, day=07, hour=17, minute=06, second=11]
MyDateTimeFormat [year=2014, month=01, day=07, hour=17, minute=06, second=16]
MyDateTimeFormat [year=2014, month=01, day=07, hour=17, minute=06, second=21]
```

And the result is completely wrong:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your loop that populates the chart data:

```
for ( MyDateTimeFormat key : hm.keySet() ) {
          out.print("data.addRow([new Date("+key.year+","+key.month+","+key.day+","+key.hour+","+key.minute+","+key.second+"), "+hm.get(key)+"]);"); 
      }%>
```

if the variable **hm** is a hashmap, then this will be unordered which might explain why the chart looks the way it does.

You could either change the chart to a scatter chart or sorting the keyset before populating the var **data**

Comment: You can also call `data.sort(0);` to sort the data in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The preceding answer from David Hodgson explains the cause of my problem.

To know the insert order of the elements in a collection like HashMap is not possible. If you want to know this order, you may use LinkedHashMap. In my case, this class solved the problem.

LinkedHashMap is similar to HashMap, the only difference between them is that LinkedHashMap knows the insert order.

Thank you, David Hodgson!